# Set size of object in Maya - scale values vs. exact units

Tags: python, scaling, maya

I'd like to adjust the width and height of a poly plane using the "xform" command, or any other python command that can accomplish the desired result. I know the exact size in centimeters that I'd like to set this plane to, but cannot seem to find a way to adjust the width and height dimensions using these centimeter values. All I see are scale parameters (visible in the channel box), where the Scale X value for my plane is 1, while the *actual* width is 73.5 (can be seen from hitting ctrl-t). Is there a painless way of setting the width and height of a plane using my centimeter values? If not- does anyone have any advice on how I tackle this problem?

Answer (score 2):

For all the poly creation commands you can actually specify units as strings instead of numbers.

For example:

```
cmds.polyCube(width = '1in', height = '1cm', depth = '1ft')
```

this will set the linear size regardless of the scene settings.  You can do the same thing with the `move` command:

```
cmds.move('1ft', x=True)
```

Support for this syntax is a bit inconsistent across maya; in theory any command which accepts linear position data *might* take this syntax but you may have to experiment a bit to find out which ones work.  Typically things that interact with physics (dynamics, hair, fluids and so on) are usually expecting metric units.

Answer (score 1):

The default units in Maya are centimeters, so assuming you haven't change your units you can simply apply your measurements directly on the `polyPlane`'s `width` and `height` attributes instead of scaling it. (These would on its shape, not its transform).

Here's an example to create a 40cm x 60cm plane:

```
import maya.cmds as cmds
cmds.polyPlane(width=40, height=60)
```

Comment: What I want to do is edit the size of the poly plane, as opposed to creating a new one. My script needs to size this same plane repeatedly. Any other ideas (thanks for the response Green Cell!)?

Comment: Does your object still have a `polyPlane` shape in its inputs? If so you can still edit its width and height directly with `cmds.setAttr`, otherwise it might be a bit trickier.

Comment: That was what I was looking for Green Cell- THANK YOU!